# Use grep inside a if statement

Tags: shell, if-statement, grep

I have to look if a file has the work `England`. I have used grep 
This is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/htmlFiles/
echo "Starting"
if `grep -inE "england" maps.html` ; then 
  echo "yaaaay"
fi
```

But the output is:

```
Starting
./trial.sh: line 4: 22:: command not found
```

Why doesn't it return `yaaaay` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backtick substitution will return the output of the command.  In this case, you are outputting the line number with `grep`'s output, following by the matching line.  Hence, there appears to be something on line 22, but the shell tries to execute the command `22:`, which then fails.

The variant you have posted as a followup answer will work, as grep returns 0 on a successful match, but 1 if the match fails.

Comment: It will find matches properly, yes.  If you supply it a string which is not present in the file, it should not echo "yaaaay".

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/htmlFiles/
echo "Starting"
if  grep -qinE "england" maps.html  ; then 
    echo "yaaaay"
fi
```

Gave me the required output. Is that a good practise?

Comment: Yes, `-q` is how grep is intended to be used with `if`. 
Just a few small comments regarding your example: `-q` does not make sense together with `-n`. `-E` does not make sense with a simple word search expression that does not use extended regexp.